# NGINX - redirect proxied response

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I have my nginx running in 8080 port and it has only my html's and javascript files and I have another webserver in 8000 port which basically is a json rest server. In my nginx.conf file (in 8080 port) i have something like this:

```
location /xyz {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
}
```

So when the user browser requests something in /xyz path nginx pass request to my server as expected. Now what I would like to do is when the server returns the http_response redirect that response to another url. Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Add the redirect in the port 8000 json rest server and it will redirect the user to the url you want them to go to.

Update:

You can also `return` a redirect from the REST server. For example:

```
location / {
    return 302 http://myotherserver.com;
}
```

> Stops processing and returns the specified code to a client. The non-standard code 444 closes a connection without sending a response header.

```
syntax:     return code [text];
            return code URL;
            return URL;
default:    —
context:    server, location, if
```

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return

Comment: Ok, but in the nginx with my web application there's no way to do it?

Comment: Yes. Simply use the `return` directive. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Well, that return directive didn't work here along with the proxy_pass, because my idea was to do something like this:

`location / {
    proxy_pass http://myrestserver.com;
    return 302 http://frontendserver.com/some_page.html;
}`

So after some research I found that what i want to do works with this approach:

`location / {
    post_action @post;
    return 302 http://frontendserver.com/some_page.html;
}`

`location @post {
    proxy_pass http://myrestserver.com;
}`

But even this approach has the problem that the response cookies are  not redirected to the frontendserver.